# Адаптивный slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

столкнулся с проблемой включения и выключения слика
Допустим у меня есть блок с новостями и на разрешениях меньше 768px он становится слайдером, settings: "unslick" не отключает, медиа запрос в js через добавление отдельного класса тож не пашет, в css медиа запрос пока не делал т.к. подключено через cdn, помогите, срочно надо доделать и сдать работу

Answer (score 0):

Раз уж используешь jQuery то подойдет вот такое решение.

**html:**

```
<div id='slider'>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
  <div>your content</div>
</div>
```

**js:**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

 if ($('body').width() < 780) {

  $('#slider').slick({

  });
 }
});
```

Comment: да, спасибо, работает